# How to update a field on the form based on a select option

Tags: php, select, onchange

I have a PHP form with the following select list;

```
<select id ="MatchCaptain" name="MatchCaptain" onchange="findTeleNo(this.value)"
                        <?php 
                            $MC = $_SESSION["MatchCapt"];
                            player_load($MC);
                        ?>
                        >
                </select>
```

I also have a text field ;

```
Telephone Number:&nbsp;</b> <?php echo $_SESSION["TeleNo"]; ?></p>
```

The PHP function called by the onchange command is ;

```
    function findTeleNo($MatchCaptain){
  $db_handle = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
    $database = "matchmanagementDB";
    $db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle, $database);
    if ($db_found) {
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM `playerstb` ORDER BY `Surname` ASC, `FirstName` ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $SQL); 
    $ufullName = split_name($MatchCaptain);
    while ( $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $uName = $db_field['FirstName'];
        $uName = trim($uName);
        $Surname = $db_field['Surname'];
        $Surname = trim($Surname);
        $fullName = $uName." ".$Surname;
        if ($fullName == $ufullName )
        {
            $_SESSION["TeleNo"] = $db_field['TeleNo'];
            include "Match_sort.php";
            break;
        }
        }
}
}
```

What I am trying to do is when the Match Captains name is changed in the SELECT dropdown list then I want the FUNCTION findTeleNo() to run. Which should then reload the form with the telephone number of the New Match Captain. 
However, when I select a new Match Captain the onchange command is ignored.
As a Septuagenarian, just learning this language, I need some help!
Does onchange work in PHP? If not what should I use?

Comment: You cannot call a PHP function directly with onchange. PHP is server side code and executed before any of the JS runs. You need to have onchange call a JS function, which can make an AJAX call to execute PHP code and get a value returned by it.

Comment: #patrick3853 Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onchange event is a javascript event, it cannot call your php function directly. You can create a javascript function that will be called when the  selects value changes and then this can make an xhr(Ajax) request to a php file which will perform a database query and return what you need it to. You could then update the page with javascript.

Comment: #aCMoFoCord   Thanks for your advice I will investigate the route. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, you need to use javascript for this.

this is example:

```js
function findTeleNo (value) {
  console.log(value);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'findTeleNo.php',
    data: {
      c_name: value
    },
    success: function (response) {
      $('#cname').text(response.cname);
      $('#teleno').text(response.teleno);
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id ="MatchCaptain" name="MatchCaptain" onchange="findTeleNo(this.value)">
      <option>choose one</option>
      <option value="A1">A1</option>
      <option value="B2">B2</option>
      <option value="C3">C3</option>
  </select>
<div>

<div>
Captain Name is: <span id="cname">empty</span>
<div>
<div>
TeleNo is: <span id="teleno">empty</span>
<div>
```

and in file findTeleNo.php you print json has cname and teleno.